# why does box extend beyond page size?

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to print a custom webpage at 89mm wide by 36mm high.

In the below code, the `<html>` and `<body>` elements are set to exactly 89mm x 36mm.  The same with the @page media size, to ensure print to pdf is resized correctly.  The div sits within and is 100% size including borders.

However, every time I try to print this, it bleeds over 2 pages, as per screenshot at the bottom.

Is this happening because `mm` is converted into `px` and it's being rounded up?  Or something else?  And is there a way to prevent this happening, apart from changing the page size?

```js
window.print()
```

```css
html, body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}

html, body {
  width: 89mm;
  height: 36mm;
  position: relative;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1mm solid black;
}

@page { 
  size: 89mm 36mm;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for us global non American unit users its a couple of issues.

PDF was designed for Printing Points at a default of 72 per inch.
Programmers like to work in whole units

Thus for PDF there is a whopping big 1 points to 0.3527777777777778 mm issue

so 89 mm X 36 mm = 252.2834 pts X 102.047 pts

thus to place one inside the other the paper needs to be 253 X 103 pts

```js
window.print()
```

```css
@media print {
  @page { 
  size: 253pt 103pt; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0! important;
}
div {
  width: 89mm;
  height: 36mm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1mm solid black;
}
```

```html
<body><div>Hello 89 mm X 36 mm World!</div></body>
```

you asked ***" is there a way to prevent this happening, apart from changing the page size?"*** And the answer is only by reduce the overspill by 0.1 point = 0.04 mm like so.

```js
window.print()
```

```css
@media print {
  @page { 
  size: 89mm 36mm; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
  }
}
body {
  margin: 0! important;
}
div {
  width: 89mm;
  height: 35.96mm;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1mm solid black;
}
```

```html
<body><div>Hello 89 mm X 35.96 mm World!</div></body>
```

[image]

However chasing file properties, will generally be fruitless unless working in point integers. Here the translation of 36 is correct but the 89 is shown as undersized and current Edge will be totally wrong for showing page dimensions, even though it wrote them !!!.

[image]